# Detect touches on different positions of a SCNNode in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, collada

I have a 3D character in .dae format which i use in ARKit. I need to have different actions for touches at different positions of the character.eg: Menu options. I use scene kit and scnnode to create ar. I just started learning AR. Can someone please help me to get this done?

Comment: You should look for hittest

Comment: @AlokSubedi :Thankyou. As i said am totally new to this, so can be more specific. Suppose my character has a head and tail. How will i know which one is clicked? I understand that by using hit test i can detect if my character was clicked or not. But since my character is a single dad file; how will i differentiate the touches?

Comment: I cannot test it for next two days but there is localCoordinates for hittest that gives you taped coordinates in node

Comment: Another option would be to get the texture coordinates from the hittest result, use those to get the color from the texture. Based on that info you may be able to differentiate between the hair and face skin color etc. Even though it is a single dae file, the object might consist of several elements. The geometryindex can then be used. Yet another option, doable depending on face count, is to use the face index value from the hittest. You would have to map the faces to separate areas in a list first.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using hit test.I was having different meshes for different parts in my model. So simply calling node.name from hit test gets me which node was selected.
Thanks all.